# How to Render Dynamic Xaml String in User Control WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, grid

I have cretated Grid with multiple rows and two columns based on the data am getting. Now i have a Xaml string. How to render in my User Control on load. Have to render from my viewmodel.How to do that.?

Real Scenario,

I will receive number of images from database. Have to display two images in each row. But i can not create number of rows constant. Because it will be based on the Dynamic data. IF data is 10 i have to create 5 rows, less means rows also will be reduced.

So Am planning to create xaml in Viewmodel based on the data. But how to render it in my User Control.

Comment: This isn't necessary at all. Instead of parsing a piece of XAML, you could as well create the UI elements programatically. Or even better, add layout related properties to your view model, and use an ItemsControl with an appropriate ItemsPanel and ItemContainerStyle, that binds to the view model properties.

Comment: Just create a custom UserControl to take the images from the ViewModel and handle all layout.  Creating UI in your ViewModel isn't MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution,

**View Model:**

```
public class ViewModel : PropertyChangedMonitor
    {
        ObservableCollection<ImageModel> _imageList;
        public ViewModel()
        {
            _imageList = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();
            ImageList.Add(new ImageModel { ImageName = "/ImageLoad;component/Images/1.png" });
            ImageList.Add(new ImageModel { ImageName = "/ImageLoad;component/Images/2.png" });
            ImageList.Add(new ImageModel { ImageName = "/ImageLoad;component/Images/3.png" });
            ImageList.Add(new ImageModel { ImageName = "/ImageLoad;component/Images/4.png" });
            ImageList.Add(new ImageModel { ImageName = "/ImageLoad;component/Images/5.png" });
            Columns = 2;
        }



        public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> ImageList
        {
            get
            {
                return _imageList;
            }

        }


        private int _column;

        public int Columns
        {
            get
            {
                return _column;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_column != value)
                {
                    _column = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Columns");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**Image Model Class:**

```
public class ImageModel
    {
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
    }
```

**And your User control :**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageLoad.ImageDisplay"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageLoad"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ImageLoad"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:ViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Columns, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Thanks @MANIKANDAN NAGALAKSHMI . It Works.